# How to parse this specific JSON response

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, xcode

I have a JSON response that can be found [here](http://backpack.tf/api/IGetPrices/v4/?key=).

I've parsed JSON reponses in the past using `NSArray` and `NSDictionary`, but the documentation (found [here](http://backpack.tf/api/prices)) for the encoding of the JSON response is confusing.

For example, in this sample response:

```
{
    "response": {
        "success": 1,
        "current_time": 1392754263,
        "raw_usd_value": 0.31,
        "items": {
            "Kritzkrieg": {
                "defindex": {
                    "0": 35
                },
                "prices": {
                    "11": {
                        "Tradable": {
                            "Craftable": {
                                "0": {
                                    "currency": "keys",
                                    "value": 32,
                                    "value_high": 34,
                                    "last_update": 1388253643,
                                    "difference": 21
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "3": {
                        "Tradable": {
                            "Craftable": {
                                "0": {
                                    "currency": "metal",
                                    "value": 0.33,
                                    "last_update": 1379423777,
                                    "difference": -0.11
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "6": {
                        "Tradable": {
                            "Craftable": {
                                "0": {
                                    "currency": "metal",
                                    "value": 0.05,
                                    "last_update": 1336410088,
                                    "difference": 0
                                }
                            },
                            "Non-Craftable": {
                                "0": {
                                    "currency": "metal",
                                    "value": 0.05,
                                    "last_update": 1362791812,
                                    "difference": 0.03
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
        }
    }
}
```

Only certain NSDictionaries contain the key "Craftable", "Non-Craftable", etc.

When I go about parsing my response, how would I be able to accomplish this?

My code so far:

```
+ (NSArray *)groupsFromJSON:(NSData *)objectNotation error:(NSError **)error
{
    NSError *localError = nil;
    NSDictionary *parsedObject = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:objectNotation options:0 error:&localError];

    if (localError != nil) {
        *error = localError;
        return nil;
    }

    NSMutableArray *groups = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSDictionary *results = [parsedObject objectForKey:@"response"];
    NSDictionary *items = [results objectForKey:@"items"];

    for (NSDictionary *groupDic in items) {
        TF2 *tf2 = [[TF2 alloc] init];
        NSDictionary *groupDick = [items objectForKey:groupDic];
        NSDictionary *prices = [groupDick valueForKey:@"prices"];
        for(NSDictionary *groupDicky in prices) {
            NSDictionary *groupDic1 = [groupDicky objectForKey:prices];
            for(NSDictionary *groupDic2 in groupDic1) {
                NSDictionary *tradable = [groupDic2 valueForKey:@"Tradable"];
                for(NSDictionary *groupDic3 in tradable) {
                    NSDictionary *craftable = [groupDic3 valueForKey:@"Craftable"];
                    NSDictionary *uncraftable = [groupDic3 valueForKey:@"Non-Craftable"];

                NSDictionary *untradable = [groupDic2 valueForKey:@"Non-Tradable"];
                for(NSDictionary *groupDick4 in tradable) {
                    NSDictionary *craftable2 = [groupDick4 valueForKey:@"Craftable"];
                    NSDictionary *uncraftable2 = [groupDick4 valueForKey:@"Non-Craftable"];
                }
            }

        }
        //[groups addObject:list];
    }

    return groups;
}
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to extract out of this JSON?

Comment: @shai I am trying to value for "currency" in the response

Comment: You parse JSOM with `NSJSONSerialization`. After that you just have a structure of Objective-C array and dictionary object, it is no longer JSON. IOW you are not parsing JSON, just accessing items from a native object.

Comment: @Zaph I know this. I have another method that parses the response. This method simply finds the keys for the values I need the response.

Comment: Offhand it looks valid, if a little screwy.  When they use non-literals for keys like that you generally need to iterate through the dictionary, treating it like it was an array (which it should have been).

Answer (score 1):

`NSDictionary` returns `nil` for a key that doesn't exist in this dictionary:

```
NSDictionary *craftable = [groupDic3 valueForKey:@"Craftable"];
// craftable is nil here
```

It means that any the following calls return `nil`as well:

```
NSDictionary* dict = [craftable valueForKey:@"0"];  // nil
NSString* currency = [dict valueForKey:@"currency"];  // nil
```

That is, if `"Craftable"` or `"Non-Craftable"` contains `currency` then you get this value, otherwise you get `nil`. Isn't this enough to understand if data you need is available?

Comment: The NSString "currency" will have multiple values depending on if the NSDictionary contains an NSDictionary for "Craftable", "Non-Craftable", or both. Would I then have to use an if statement to check if these NSDictionaries exist?

Comment: Sorry, didn't get your question. Just extract currency value from a section which you need ("Craftable" or "Non-Craftable") and use that value, if it's not nil. If you need values from both sections then store them in array, or in dictionary, or simply in several variables, etc.